# Create a condition with a difference in dates by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a flag for unique people (defined by id) that have a flight duration that is over 14 hours and they have another flight greater than or equal to 25 days after the 14-hour flight.

To tackle this, I decided to use an if-else statement where the max date grouped by id was subtracted by row date, but the flagging only seems to work for cases where the first flight is above 14 hours.

```
#Setup Data Frame
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5)
flght_dur <- c(27,13,13,17,19,12,7,9,27,14,13,45)
flght_dt <- as.Date(c("2016-03-29","2016-09-01","2015-07-23","2016-06-16","2015-11-12","2016-03-25","2015-12-23","2016-05-19","2016-08-18","2016-09-27","2016-08-18","2016-09-27"))
df <- data.frame(id, flght_dur, flght_dt)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(flght_dur >= 14  && (max(as.Date(flght_dt)) -  as.Date(flght_dt)) >= 25, 1,0))
df2
```

Any suggestions on next steps would be appreciated,

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the scalar *and* condition `&&` with vectors, which will only look at the first element of the vector; To look at all possible conditions and return a scalar per group, you can use `&` on vectors and then use `any` to reduce the boolean result:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(flag = +any(flght_dur >= 14 & max(as.Date(flght_dt)) -  as.Date(flght_dt) >= 25))
    #             ^ used + here to convert boolean to 1 and 0 instead of if/else for short

df2
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   id [5]
#      id flght_dur flght_dt    flag
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     <int>
# 1    1.       27. 2016-03-29     1
# 2    1.       13. 2016-09-01     1
# 3    2.       13. 2015-07-23     0
# 4    2.       17. 2016-06-16     0
# 5    3.       19. 2015-11-12     1
# 6    3.       12. 2016-03-25     1
# 7    4.        7. 2015-12-23     1
# 8    4.        9. 2016-05-19     1
# 9    4.       27. 2016-08-18     1
#10    4.       14. 2016-09-27     1
#11    5.       13. 2016-08-18     0
#12    5.       45. 2016-09-27     0
```

Comment: This is great!  I have not heard of using "+any" before. I also did not realize that && was specific for scalar. This is very informative. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using chaining with `data.table` as follows:

```
DF[, longHaul := ifelse(flght_dur > 14, TRUE, FALSE)][, maxFlight_DATE := max(flght_dt), by = "id"][longHaul == TRUE & (maxFlight_DATE - flght_dt > 25),]
```

This is after converting your `data.frame` to `data.table` with `DF = data.table(df)`

It gives me the following output, which appears to follow the logic you want.

```
   id flght_dur   flght_dt longHaul maxFlight_DATE
1:  1        27 2016-03-29     TRUE     2016-09-01
2:  3        19 2015-11-12     TRUE     2016-03-25
3:  4        27 2016-08-18     TRUE     2016-09-27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this avoiding loops using `rollapply` as below.

```
df$sameid <- c(rollapply(df$id, width = 2, by = 1, FUN = function(x) x[1]==x[2] , align = "right"),NA)
df$nextdurcondition <- c(diff(df$flght_dt)>25 ,NA)
df$flag <- df$sameid &df$nextdurcondition
df
```

However, for these rolling functions, I personally always use loops